# LINQ order by delegate

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I have a collection of objects to be ordered by an object's field value. Current problem is that the order depends on a business logic.

```
public enum Order : byte {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3
}

public class Foo{
    public long A {get;set;}
    public long B {get;set;}
    public long C {get;set;}
}

public class Worker(){
    private Foo[] orderFoos(Foo[] foos, Func<Order, long> sort){
        return foos.OrderByDescending(f => sort(f)).ToArray(foos.Length);
    }

    public void Work(){
        Foo[] foos = getFoos();

        var orderByA = orderFoos(foos, f => f.A);
        var orderByB = orderFoos(foos, f => f.B);
        var orderByC = orderFoos(foos, f => f.C);
    }
}
```

Compiler throws an error that `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Foo' to 'Order'`. Are there any workarounds or solutions?

Comment: What values does `Foo.A`, `Foo.B` and `Foo.C` hold?

Comment: @NtFreX ```long```, it is mentioned in Foo class declaration.

Comment: I ment what values and not what types. Im asking because I do not really understand what you try to do.

Comment: Please remove those parentheses () next to your class names.

Comment: Does changing `orderFoos` to `private Foo[] orderFoos(Foo[] foos, Func<Foo, long> sort)
    {
        return foos.OrderByDescending(sort).ToArray();
    }` work?

Comment: @mjwills no, it's not.

Comment: @mjwills From the _syntax_ point of view it works and doesn't throws any exceptions. The actual behaviour isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code seems to work. It is a small change to the `orderFoos` method, with some sample code for you to test the results.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public enum Order : byte
{
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3
}

public class Foo
{
    public long A { get; set; }
    public long B { get; set; }
    public long C { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    private Foo[] orderFoos(Foo[] foos, Func<Foo, long> sort)
    {
        return foos.OrderByDescending(sort).ToArray();
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        Foo[] foos = { new Foo() { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 }, new Foo() { A = 10, B = 1, C = 2 }, new Foo() { A = -1, B = 1, C = 10 } };

        var orderByA = orderFoos(foos, f => f.A);
        var orderByB = orderFoos(foos, f => f.B);
        var orderByC = orderFoos(foos, f => f.C);

        Console.WriteLine(orderByA.First().A); // I expect the second to be first here so 10
        Console.WriteLine(orderByB.First().A); // I expect the first to be first here so 1
        Console.WriteLine(orderByC.First().A); // I expect the third to be first here so -1
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var worker = new Worker();

        worker.Work();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it is exaclty what I do with proxiing ```Order``` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you wanted to achieve is sorting on different fields. You may not need to have Order enum if it's only for that purpose and replace:

```
private Foo[] orderFoos(Foo[] foos, Func<Order, long> sort){
    return foos.OrderByDescending(f => sort(f)).ToArray(foos.Length);
}
```

into

```
private Foo[] orderFoos(Foo[] foos, Func<Foo, long> sort){
    return foos.OrderByDescending(sort).ToArray(foos.Length);
}
```

NB: I'm not sure your intention with adding foos.Length in the ToArray method, but supposedly that's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work as expected but it gave me a better understanding of how delegates work.

Answer (score 0):

@hsoesanto gave a good solution but it doesn't work the way I expected it would be.
So I've created temporary workaround.

```
private  Func<Foo, long> GetOrderFunction(Order orderType)
{
    switch (orderType)
    {
        case Order.A:
            return (f) => f.A;
        case Order.B:
            return (f) => f.B;
        case Order.C:
            return (f) => f.C;
     }
}

private Foo[] orderFoos(Foo[] foos, Order order)
{
    var orderFunction = GetOrderFunction(order);
    return foos
        .OrderByDescending(f => orderFunction (f))
        .ToArray(foos.Length);
}
```